# How to see changes being done to registry?

Tags: windows-registry, windows-11, start-menu, desktop-customization

I am using StartAllBack to customize my Win11, but I would like to switch to Start11. The thing is SAB has a feature where it colorizes even dialog windows like copy/move dialogs and errors and I would like to keep those. I am pretty sure SAB just edits a few registry entries and I would like to identify which ones. I tried Event Viewer but I did not find anything, probably used it wrong. Any tips on identifying these changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a tool such as free Nirsoft's [RegistryChangesView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/registry_changes_view.html) or Sysinternals' [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to capture the state of the registry *before* installing SAB and *after* its installation, and use the tool to "diff" the two to see only changes. There are [more alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/registrychangesview/) to those tools.

Of course, check any software at [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload) before installing.

Answer (score 3):

Use sysinternals "[Procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)"

You will need to create filters to make the information digestible to normal human beings.

1. Isolate `Process name contains StartAllBack` (assuming that the process name contains this).
2. Isolate `Operation starts with reg`
3. Do the deed.
4. Examine the output.

Filter more as needed.

Rejoice.